# Thread exiting with uncaught exception. Loading image from server

Tags: android, sql-server, android-asynctask, imageview, inputstream

I am trying to create a viewPager that loads images from a server I set up using XAMPP. However every time I run the app on my Samsung Galaxy S3, As soon as I open the activity, the application just closes without so much as an error or ANR message, It just ends immediately. In my logCat, all it says is: Thread exiting with an uncaught exception. Below is my code, please tell how to fix this. I apologize for the messy code.

**THE ACTIVITY**

```
    package com.example.nowlpractice;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Display;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class ImageDetailActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_IMAGE = "extra_image";

    private ImagePagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    ImageView mImageView;
    public static int width;
    public static int height;

    // A static dataset to back the ViewPager adapter
    public final static Integer[] imageResIds = new Integer[] {
            R.drawable.koala, R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2,
            R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.koala, R.drawable.img5, R.drawable.img6,
            R.drawable.img7, R.drawable.img8, R.drawable.img9, R.drawable.img10,   
    R.drawable.img11,
            R.drawable.img12, R.drawable.img13, R.drawable.img14, R.drawable.img15,
            R.drawable.img16, R.drawable.img17, R.drawable.img18, R.drawable.img19, 
    R.drawable.img20};

    public final static String[] imageUrl = new String[] {
   "img","img1","img2","img3","img4","img5","img6","img7","img8","img9","img10","img11",       
    "img13","img14",
        "img15","img16",
        "img17","img18","img19","img20"
    };



    public static String[] names = new String[] {
            "KYRI IOULIANOU", "THABANG MNGUNI", "YIANNI CREASE",
            "STEFANO CREASE", "CONSTANTINOS PRIMIKIRIOS", "MEGAN PATTERSON"
    };

    public static String[] clubsNames = new String[] {
        "KONG", "TABOO", "VELVET",
        "GREENSIDE", "BIG MAMAS HOUSE", "HOOTERS"

    };

    public static LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_detail); // Contains just a ViewPager

     // Get max available VM memory, exceeding this amount will throw an
        // OutOfMemory exception. Stored in kilobytes as LruCache takes an
        // int in its constructor.
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

        // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                // The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than
                // number of items.
                Log.d("Cache", "Inititated mem cache");
                return bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024;

            }

            @Override
            protected void entryRemoved( boolean evicted, String key, Bitmap oldValue,  
    Bitmap newValue ) {
              oldValue.recycle();
              Log.d("REMOVED FROM CACHE", "Bitmap removed from cache");
            }
        };

        Display myDisplay = ((WindowManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        width =myDisplay.getWidth();
        height=myDisplay.getHeight();

        mAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myviewpager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        Log.d("ViewPager", "Launched PageAdapter");

        ScrollTextView scrolltext=(ScrollTextView) findViewById(R.id.scrolltext);
        scrolltext.setText("WELCOME TO NIGHT OWL");
        scrolltext.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        scrolltext.startScroll(width/2500.0, true);

    }

    public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
            mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
        return mMemoryCache.get(key);
    }

    public void loadBitmap(String resId, ImageView imageView) {
        Log.d("LoadBitmap", "LoadBitmapStarted");
        final String imageKey = resId;

        final Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemCache(imageKey);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            Drawable drawable = new RoundedCornersDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_photo);
            Log.d("Start Async", "About to start async task");
            BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView, getResources(), 
    ImageDetailActivity.this);
            task.execute(resId);
        }
    }

    public static class ImagePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private final int mSize;
        int pos;

        public ImagePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int size) {
            super(fm);
            mSize = size;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mSize;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            pos = position%21;
            Log.d("Just about to launch fragment", "yOU KNOW");
            return ImageDetailFragment.newInstance(pos);

            //return ImageDetailFragment.newInstance(position);
        }
    }
    }


    //************************************************************************************
    //************************************************************************************
```

**THE FRAGMENT**

```
package com.example.nowlpractice;

import android.R.color;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ImageDetailFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String IMAGE_DATA_EXTRA = "resId";
private int mImageNum;
private ImageView mImageView;

static ImageDetailFragment newInstance(int imageNum) {
    final ImageDetailFragment f = new ImageDetailFragment();
    final Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(IMAGE_DATA_EXTRA, imageNum);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}

// Empty constructor, required as per Fragment docs
public ImageDetailFragment() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mImageNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt(IMAGE_DATA_EXTRA) : -1;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // image_detail_fragment.xml contains just an ImageView
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_detail_fragment, container, false);
    mImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    //TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    //tv.setText(ImageDetailActivity.names[mImageNum]);
    //tv.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
    //tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    //TextView tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    //tv2.setText(ImageDetailActivity.clubsNames[mImageNum]);
    //tv2.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
    //tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    return v;   
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (ImageDetailActivity.class.isInstance(getActivity())) {



        final String resId = ImageDetailActivity.imageUrl[mImageNum];

        // Call out to ImageDetailActivity to load the bitmap in a background thread
        Log.d("Fragment", "About to launch loadBitmap");
        ((ImageDetailActivity) getActivity()).loadBitmap(resId, mImageView);
        //Call to Activity to get the textView text
        //((ImageDetailActivity) getActivity()).loadText(resId, tv);
    }

    //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),  
ImageDetailActivity.imageResIds[mImageNum]);
    //RoundedCornersDrawable drawable = new RoundedCornersDrawable(getResources(), 
bmp);
    //mImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

   // final int resId = ImageDetailActivity.imageResIds[mImageNum];
   // mImageView.setImageResource(resId); // Load image into ImageView
}
}
```

**THE ASYNC TASK**

```
package com.example.nowlpractice;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {
private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
private String data = "";
Resources res;
public static Context context;

public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView, Resources mRes, Context c) {
    // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    res = mRes;
    context = c;
}

// Decode image in background.
@Override
protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
    data = "http://172.29.153.12:80/webservice/images/" + params[0];
    //TOOOOOOOOOODOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
    Bitmap bmp;
    try {
        Log.d("decode bitmap", "About to decode bitmap");
        bmp = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(res, data, 400, 400);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("Error", "MalformedUrlException");
        e.printStackTrace();
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.empty_photo);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("Error", "IOException");
        e.printStackTrace();
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.empty_photo);
    }
    //TODO ADJUST REQ DIMENSIONS ACCORDING TO SCREEN DENSITIY!!!!
    ImageDetailActivity.mMemoryCache.put(String.valueOf(params[0]), bmp);
    Log.d("ADDED TO CACHE", "Bitmap added to cache");
    Drawable drawable = new RoundedCornersDrawable(res, bmp);
    return drawable;
}

// Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Drawable bitmap) {
    if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
        final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        if (imageView != null) {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(bitmap);
            imageView.getLayoutParams().width = ImageDetailActivity.width;
            imageView.getLayoutParams().height = ImageDetailActivity.width;
        }
    }
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, String resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    if(isConnectionAvailable(context)){
        Log.d("Connection", "Connection is available, launching ulrconn");
        URLConnection conn = new URL(resId).openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        Log.d("Decode", "About to decode");
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream(),null, options);
        Log.d("Decode2", "Just decoded bitmap");


    //BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream(),null, options);

    }



    if(!isConnectionAvailable(context)){
        Log.d("No connection", "No connection");
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.empty_photo);
    }
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.empty_photo);
    //else{ return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.empty_photo); }
    //return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width >= reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height/2;
    final int halfWidth = width/2;

    //Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

return inSampleSize;
}

public static boolean isConnectionAvailable(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()
                && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()
                && netInfo.isAvailable()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

**THE LOGCAT**

```
08-12 21:05:14.290: D/OpenGLRenderer(30029): Enabling debug mode 0
08-12 21:05:15.255: D/ViewPager(30029): Launched PageAdapter
08-12 21:05:15.275: D/Just about to launch fragment(30029): yOU KNOW
08-12 21:05:15.275: D/Just about to launch fragment(30029): yOU KNOW
08-12 21:05:15.280: D/Fragment(30029): About to launch loadBitmap
08-12 21:05:15.280: D/LoadBitmap(30029): LoadBitmapStarted
08-12 21:05:15.285: D/Start Async(30029): About to start async task
08-12 21:05:15.285: D/decode bitmap(30029): About to decode bitmap
08-12 21:05:15.285: D/Fragment(30029): About to launch loadBitmap
08-12 21:05:15.285: D/LoadBitmap(30029): LoadBitmapStarted
08-12 21:05:15.285: D/Start Async(30029): About to start async task
08-12 21:05:15.290: D/decode bitmap(30029): About to decode bitmap
08-12 21:05:15.290: W/dalvikvm(30029): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught  
exception  
(group=0x41f8c700)
08-12 21:05:15.290: W/dalvikvm(30029): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught   
exception   
(group=0x41f8c700)
08-12 21:05:15.290: I/Process(30029): Sending signal. PID: 30029 SIG: 9
```

I have tried using logs to find the problem but that didnt help. Ive tried everything

Comment: post the error stack trace

Comment: post your logcat completely , these are filtered, remove any filter and post it again

Comment: @mmlooloo That is exactly what my logCat produced. No filters, that's why the problem is so strange to me...

Comment: @tyczj Where do i find the stack trace

Comment: No you are showing your Log.d messages not all errors, logcat == stack trace

Comment: @mmlooloo I am showing my logcat, it literally just gave me those 2 uncaught exception errors, i think theres something wrong with my url, i removed the if statement for the connection and its going through but still crashing with nullPointerException at the bitmap, definetely something wrong with the decodeInputStream block of code

Comment: @user3446535 No brother you are showing just Log.d messages , i do not know why, if you are using eclipse at the left part of logcat window there is a window that manage your log cat filter, also at the top right of logcat there is a spinner that you can select what information to show: errors verbose an so on unless you do not show complete logcat i can not help you and suppose any other SO people  also do not like helping just by reading these lines of code.

Comment: @user3446535 look at this logcat , this is a compelete one man, not the above one.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278040/cannot-launch-fragmentactivity-with-the-intent-the-same-way-as-in-other-app-whe

Comment: @mmlooloo Friend. I know what a logCat is I promise you. That is all it showed I just left out the beginning parts coz they are pointless and i only pasted the errors. Can you please help me...

Comment: my brother your logcat is filtered with your `Log.d` code that you put it in your code. i can not help you with this log. i am sure it is filtered, just play around the page to see what i told you in my comments. or comments all `Log.d` code and then you will see complete logcat.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to investigate your code. I would simply remove all loading bitmaps related code and replace with [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library.

This library handles nicely loading images from different sources in the background. Images can be cached, you can specify temporary placeholders, error placeholders etc.

There is no point to implement it yourself if you don't know how.

If you really have to do it by yourself then read first [Android Developers page](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html). Google folks explain how to implement it in great detail.