# Cannot launch FragmentActivity with the intent the same way as in other app, where it perfectly works

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-fragmentactivity

I have got the following problem. Separately from my big app I have created a simple swipe view with tabs in order to place there later some fragments of this big app. In main activity I have got a button. It launces the corresponding onClick method and then this FragmentActivity is started. I have got absolutely the same code(actually this code used) in big app(this fragmentacitvity is launched with the corresponding intent absolutely the same way from main activity). It works perfectly in the separate app for swipe views, but doesn't work in the big app. Here is what i get in the log after pressing the button to start this fragmentactivity with intent:

```
 08-13 07:03:19.238: W/dalvikvm(25184): No implementation found for native Ldalvik/system/VMRuntime;.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184): Pause GC
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5525)
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: 

dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184):    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc(Native Method)
08-13 07:03:19.238: E/ActivityThread(25184):    ... 15 more
08-13 07:03:19.268: D/dalvikvm(25184): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 67K, 8% free 15173K/16452K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
08-13 07:03:19.278: D/SETTINGS CONTAINER(25184): In nCreate - STAGE 2
08-13 07:03:19.278: D/SETTINGS CONTAINER(25184): In OnCreate - STAGE 3
08-13 07:03:19.278: D/SETTINGS CONTAINER(25184): In OnCreate - STAGE 4
08-13 07:03:19.283: D/SETTINGS CONTAINER(25184): In OnCreate - STAGE 5
08-13 07:03:19.283: D/SETTINGS CONTAINER(25184): In OnCreate - STAGE 6
08-13 07:03:19.283: D/SETTINGS CONTAINER(25184): In OnCreate - STAGE 7
08-13 07:03:19.283: D/AndroidRuntime(25184): Shutting down VM
08-13 07:03:19.283: W/dalvikvm(25184): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d40c08)
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184): Process: com.example.bigapp, PID: 25184
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

{com.example.bigapp/com.example.bigapp.ContainerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184):    at com.example.bigapp.ContainerActivity.onCreate(ContainerActivity.java:48)
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184):    at      android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184):    ... 11 more
```

Here is the code(it is the same in both cases)

### ContainerActivity.java

```
    package com.example.bigapp;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    public class ContainerActivity extends FragmentActivity 
    {

    ViewPager Tab;
    TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_container);
    Log.d("SETTINGS CONTAINER","In nCreate - STAGE 2");
    TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Log.d("SETTINGS CONTAINER","In OnCreate - STAGE 3");
    Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    Log.d("SETTINGS CONTAINER","In OnCreate - STAGE 4");
    Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
            new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) 
                {
                  actionBar = getActionBar();
                  actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);                    
                  }
            });
    Log.d("SETTINGS CONTAINER","In OnCreate - STAGE 5");
    Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
    Log.d("SETTINGS CONTAINER","In OnCreate - STAGE 6");
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    Log.d("SETTINGS CONTAINER","In OnCreate - STAGE 7");
    //Enable Tabs on Action Bar
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    Log.d("SETTINGS CONTAINER","In OnCreate - STAGE 8");


    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction ft) 
        {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
               Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
           }
       @Override
       public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
           FragmentTransaction ft) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       }};

     //Add New Tab


actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Android").setTabListener(tabListener));
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("iOS").setTabListener(tabListener));
   actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Windows").setTabListener(tabListener));

## TabPagerAdapter.java ##
    package com.example.bigapp;

    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

    public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            //Fragement for Android Tab
            return new Android();
        case 1:
           //Fragment for Ios Tab
            return new ios();
       case 2:
            //Fragment for Windows Tab
            return new windows();
        }
       return null;
     }
     @Override
     public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 3; //No of Tabs
    }
      }
```

### MainActivity.java

```
public void launchSettings(View view)
    {
        Intent toLaunch = new Intent(this, ContainerActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(toLaunch);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    }
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bigapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.bigapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.bigapp.ContainerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_container" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

I've compared the versions of the v4 support libraries, cleared the bin, cleared the project many times, compared the manifests of these two apps - everything is the same, but it doesn't work. Thank You in advance for Your help.

Comment: *Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 07:03:19.288: E/AndroidRuntime(25184): at com.example.bigapp.ContainerActivity.onCreate(ContainerActivity.java:48)* What is the code on line 48?

Comment: @AndrewT. is correct

Comment: Thank You! the code is:    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

Comment: I know that it is this line, which causes the crash, but I just cannot figure out - what is wrong with it